# load data from chrome.storage into vue.js data

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-app

I'm building a chrome app and I use Vue.js for the options page.
So I want to load settings from the chrome storage and put it into the vue data.

My problem is, that i can not access the vue compontens from inside the chrome storage callback. Every time i call it inside the callback, all vue elements are undefined. 
Is there a way, to let the chrome storage cb function return a value, or give it an extra callback.

Here is my code

```
name: 'app',
    data: function () {
        return {
            data []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        init: function() {
            chrome.storage.sync.get('series', function (storageData) {
                this.data = storageData   //this is not possible, because this.data is undefined
                })
            });
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using ES6 and transpiling (*preferred approach*). Note: arrow functions don't create a new context.

```
init: function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('series', storageData => {
        this.data = storageData
    });
}
```

ES5 workaround:

```
init: function() {
    var self = this;
    chrome.storage.sync.get('series', function (storageData) {
        self.data = storageData
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks a lot